How to check if my spark application is utilizing all the available resources or not?
I am reading data from kafka in spark after doing some transformation loading it to a database.
When I start my job via spark-submit I can see it starts the number of containers as mentioned in spark submit but I can see from resource manager ui that the container which is running the driver process has logs only from my application and in rest of the executors log I see only GC related logs?
My doubt here is that is my cluster fully utilized ? or only one container is doing the actual work and rest is just sitting ideal.
I am reading from about 50 topics and each are partitioned(with minimum 4 partition )
I am using EMR 6.5 which comes with spark 3.1.2 and scala 2.12.14
my spark submit :
spark-submit --name read-from-kafka --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn  --conf  spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf spark.sql.caseSensitive=true --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=50 --conf spark.driver.memory=5300M --class com.XXX.XXX.reports.unifiedLoader --jars file:////home/hadoop/lib/* --executor-memory 5600M   --conf "spark.alert.duration=4" --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=6 --executor-cores 2 --files /home/hadoop/reports/log4j.properties,/home/hadoop/reports/application_commonJob_cdc.conf,/home/hadoop/reports/sendalert.sh --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" radfromkafka_2.12-1.0.jar application_commonJob_cdc.conf
Cluster configuration:
3 workers with 32gb and 8vcpus
1 master with 32 gb and 8 vcpus
below are the logs from executor container :
2024-04-30T14:00:28.018+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 126464K->12782K(147456K)] 126464K->12798K(484864K), 0.0088915 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:28.258+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 64103K->8546K(147456K)] 64119K->8570K(484864K), 0.0057556 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:28.264+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 8546K->0K(147456K)] [ParOldGen: 24K->8255K(202752K)] 8570K->8255K(350208K), [Metaspace: 20274K->20274K(1067008K)], 0.0303067 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:29.062+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 126464K->8167K(147456K)] 134719K->16431K(350208K), 0.0034351 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:29.320+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 98819K->7312K(198656K)] 107083K->15583K(401408K), 0.0050790 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:29.325+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 7312K->0K(198656K)] [ParOldGen: 8271K->13221K(326656K)] 15583K->13221K(525312K), [Metaspace: 33825K->33822K(1079296K)], 0.0266719 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:29.852+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 177664K->7411K(198656K)] 190885K->20641K(525312K), 0.0062175 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:38.112+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 185075K->9928K(244736K)] 198305K->23166K(571392K), 0.0067299 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:38.970+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 208351K->13300K(255488K)] 221589K->28096K(582144K), 0.0106491 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:38.981+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 13300K->0K(255488K)] [ParOldGen: 14795K->23697K(455168K)] 28096K->23697K(710656K), [Metaspace: 53584K->52539K(1099776K)], 0.0873161 secs] [Times: user=0.37 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:40.097+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 242176K->8165K(329216K)] 265873K->31871K(784384K), 0.0062505 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]  2024-04-30T14:00:42.873+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 321091K->15345K(328704K)] 344796K->172435K(783872K), 0.0319163 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.03, real=0.03 secs] 

You need to enable spark-ui to see the utilizatiion of your cluster
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/emr-access-spark-ui

Sorry if my question was not clear.Spark web ui is accessible to me and I can see containers are running but what I don't see there is logs from my application only the container which is running the driver process has application logs and rest are just showing gc related logs.


You can enable Ganglia while creating the cluster. Ganglia will help with cluster metrics.

Here is the AWS documentation for Ganglia - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/view_Ganglia.html


Other way is to use the cloudwatch events - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html

From the above link - Metrics are updated every five minutes and automatically collected and pushed to CloudWatch for every Amazon EMR cluster.



